# How to convert between volumetric HKUnits?

Tags: swift, healthkit

I'm currently working on adding localisation support for volumetric units in my app. For example I want to be able to change from fluid ounces to litres and back again. Basically I want to support all the volumetric units that HKUnit supports with `.dietaryWater`.

Apple does say that `"You can request the value from a quantity object in any compatible units."`, but are very unclear how one would do this. ([link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantity))

How can I do conversations between units without writing the math myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided, under Working With Units:

```swift
var value = HKQuantity(unit: .fluidOunceUS(), doubleValue: 42)
var convertedValue = value.doubleValue(for: .liter())
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantity/1615245-doublevalue

Answer (score 1):

Foundation includes a `Measurement` structure that allows for a wide variety of unit conversions. For example, to convert from fluid ounces to liters:

```
let fluidOz = 32.0
let liters = Measurement(value: fluidOz, unit: UnitVolume.fluidOunces).converted(to: .liters).value
print(liters) // 0.946352

let degrees = 45.0
let radians = Measurement(value: degrees, unit: UnitAngle.degrees).converted(to: .radians).value
print(radians) // 0.7853981633974483
```

In addition to `UnitVolume`, there is also `UnitSpeed`, `UnitMass`, and many more.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/measurement